# How can I add skipped test cases in ExtentReports?

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

I need to add all of my skipped test cases to my ExtentReports. How can I achieve this?

I have tried below code in my *BaseTest.java*:

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(Method method)
{
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) 
    {
        ((ExtentTest) extentTest.getTest()).log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getThrowable());
    } 
    else
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            ((ExtentTest) extentTest.getTest()).log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test skipped " + result.getThrowable());
        }
        else 
        {
            ((ExtentTest) extentTest.getTest()).log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");
        }

    report.endTest(extentTest);
    report.flush(); 
}
```

Comment: Question needs to be catagorized so it gets the attention of people that can answer it ( Java)

Comment: _I have tried below code_: What is the result of your try? Did you can any error message that you can share with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing ITestListener and following methods:

```
  public interface ITestListener extends ITestNGListener {

  void onTestStart(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result);

  public void onStart(ITestContext context);

  public void onFinish(ITestContext context);

}
```

so implementation looks something like this:

```
public class test implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        ... do Your stuff for skip tests extent report here ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        ... do Your stuff for passed test extent report here ...
    }

    ... and all other methods are automatically implemented, and You don't have to check status, test will automatically enter proper methods. 


    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context){
          //init extent reports... on whatever way You do it...
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context){
        report.endTest(extentTest);
        report.flush(); 
    }

}
```

And this is generalised for all test.

Hope this helps,